# how to block code of a page of an external URL opened inside an iframe from HTTP to HTTPS (cross browser domain) in all browsers?

Tags: jquery, iframe, cors, yql, html4

I program using (javascript) jQuery and HTML4, i'm not an full expert i just know a little.

I have a page with an IFRAME that points to a DIFFERENT DOMAIN'S page of a bank's site to retrieve some exchange value after validation of a form.
this is my HTML part simplified:

```
<iframe id="iframeBank" name="iframeBank" src="http://siteBank.com/?lang=it" onload="blockLink">  
// the link here works even if it is a HTTPS Protocol with SSL 
//(still i cannot understand why it shows HTTP on site sources while it IS a HTTPS) 
    <p>your browser does not support iframes.<p/>
</iframe>
```

In the page iside the IFRAME i want to disable the ability to click only one link amongst all and let the user to navigate the rest.
This is what i see searching the link in the chrome inspector when the page is rendered in the browser

```
<iframe id="iframeBank" name="iframeBank" src="http://siteBank.com/?lang=it" onload="blockLink">
    #document
        <html>
            #shadow-root (open)
                <#shadow> ==%0
                 ...
                 ...
                </shadow>
                <style></style>
            <head>
            ...
            ...
            </head>
            <body>
                <a href="http://homePageOfTheBank.com">
                    <img src="img/logo.gif" aling="absmiddle" alt="HOME PAGE">
                </a>
                <center>
                ...
                ...
                </center>
            </body>
        </html>
    </iframe>
```

Here is some code i tried in a first place without knowing the cross browser issue:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //this is a first try to intercept 
    //the a tag inside the body and block the event to start
    $(document).ready(function(){   
     $('body a').click (function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      e.stopImmediatePropagation();
     });
    });

    //this is a second try
    $("body").on ("mousedown mouseup click", "a", function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      });
    }); 

 //this is a third way but all theese codes 
 //works only inside the same domain policy
 function blockLink(){
  $("body").on ("mousedown mouseup click", "a", function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
  });
 }
 </script>
```

i have read about javascript .preventdefault(); method but it is impossible to use it this way.

i have read about CROSS-ORIGIN HTTP reques(cors) but i cannot understand where to put the code and how to use it to get my goal.

i have read about Yahoo Query Language (YQL) but i cannot understand how to use it and where and how to write the right code (lacks of a tutorial with explanations). Even if it looks simple.

I do not know how to implement a proxy server.

I wonder if is it possible to solve this problem using only jQuery.

All i need is that inside that frame the LINK to the HOME PAGE is DISABLED and this must be valid for ALL THE sub PAGES INSIDE the IFRAME the user will pass through to retrieve the final exchange values (the position of the tag is always the same as in the example shown,the "only" main change is the page name always in a different domain than mine).

I also have tried to modify

```
document.domain="myDomain";
```

inside a  page opened by the iframe, but still no results..

I CANNOT USE PLUGINS this is an app that should contain all the code inside of it .

Comment: Unfortunately, _I think_ that you can't edit the HTML code from another page _even if you have that page in a iframe element_. You said: `I have read about CROSS-ORIGIN HTTP request(cors)...` in simple words: _you can't make such changes, for securiry reasons_. Can you edit your question including the source of the page in which you want block the link(s)? or, can you please explain what do you want get from that page?

Comment: Thank you, in my main page there's a link that opens a page with an iframe that goes to the exchange page of a bank where it is possible to find the exchange rate.  All the bank's pages have a link that redirect to the home page of the bank. I need to block this specific link. There should be a way like JSONP to get rid of this CROSS BROWSER policy. My problem is that in my iframe the user have to go thorugh some pages inside the bank's site to reach the needed value of exchange.

Comment: Other option could be: extract the info you need using YQL, [here is a example](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=select+*+from+html+where+url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fweb.tmxmoney.com%2Fquote.php%3Fqm_symbol%3DTSX%22++and+xpath%3D'%2F%2Fdiv%5Bcontains(%40id%2C%22quote_data%22)%5D'), but you have to change the query. If you consider this option, I suggest you update your question with the URL of the source _i. e, the URL you use in your IFRAME_

Comment: It's a good suggestion, I changed the question's title today.